# Finding the derivative of an implicit function with respect to $t$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I've been asked to differentiate the equation $x^7 + 7xy^2 = 7$ with respect to the variable $t$ and express $\frac{dy}{dt}$ in terms of $\frac{dx}{dt}$. I tried to solve it like this:

$\frac{d}{dt}(x^7) + 7\frac{d}{dt}(xy^2) = \frac{d}{dt}(7)$

Using the product rule:
$7x^6\frac{dx}{dt} + 7(\frac{d}{dt}(x)y^2 + x\frac{d}{dt}(y^2)) = 0$

$7x^6\frac{dx}{dt} + 7(y^2\frac{dx}{dt} + 2xy\frac{dy}{dt}) = 0$

Factoring out the 7:
$x^6\frac{dx}{dt} + y^2\frac{dx}{dt} + 2xy\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$

Then isolating $\frac{dy}{dt}$ on one side:
$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{x^6\frac{dx}{dt} - y^2\frac{dx}{dt}}{2xy}$

WebWork tells me this is incorrect and wolframalpha has been no help since it doesn't understand how to differentiate with respect to a variable not in the function (or I don't know how to input it into wolframalpha).

Am I misunderstanding the question or is there a mistake in my algebra?

Comment: Sign error? The terms in the numerator should be added not subtracted. Also, did you try grouping to factorise out the dx/dt? Maybe your Web answering system expects that (I would as well).

Comment: Flipped the sign and factored out dx/dt and it was accepted! Thanks, it really was just a sign error... I'm new on here so how do I mark your comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = -\dfrac{\dfrac{dx}{dt}(x^6 + y^2)}{2xy}$$